# Sum of Look Up Value using VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup, lookup

I have a table containing the oil and natural gas pipelines with three main columns:
1) Column A with Country of Origin (USA)
2) Column B with Year of Starting (say 2015)
3) Capacity of the Pipeline in Barrels/day. (say 1000)

There are rows with similar value of country and year since each year a country establishes multiple pipelines. I want to sum the capacity of all plants in a year for each country. The construct of the result sheet is Countries on X axis and Year on the Y axis and the values in the table should be the sum of capacity column for that country in that year.

I have tried using HLOOKUP and LOOKUP to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: use a pivot table

Comment: VLOOKUP returns one value where the table matches one criteria.  But you want to return the sum of multiple values so VLOOKUP isn't going to work.  You should use a pivot table because it will return ALL the sums of all the countries and years at once.  If you don't want to you can use the SUMIF function instead of VLOOKUP to get the sum for each country and year but then you need a whole bunch of SUMIF formulas - the pivot table is much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally blanked that I could use a Pivot table.Thank you!